# Property of surjective, composed linear maps.

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $T \in Hom(V,W)$ and $S \in Hom(W,X)$.

Under the assumption that $S \circ T$ and $S$ are surjections, prove that
$$R(T) +_S \ker(S)=W,$$
Where $+_S$ represents the set-sum, $R(T$) is the range of $T$, and $\ker(S)$ is the null space of S.

I have attempted to solve the above problem, but I couldn't find a proper solution. My steps so far:

1. Since $S \circ T$ is surjective, then $(S \circ T)[V]=S(T[V])=S[R(T)]=X$. Moreover, since $\ker(S)$ is the null space of $S$, it must also mean that $S[R(T)+_S\ker(S)]=S[R(T)]+_S S[\ker(S)]=S[R(T)]+_S \{0\}=S[R(T)]=X$
2. Since $S$ is surjective, then $S[W]=X.$
3. From 1) and 2), we can deduce that $S[R(T) +_S \ker(S)]=S[W]=X$.

The notation $S[A]$ indicates the image of the transformation $S$ when restricted to the set $A$.
The problem is that in step 3), we do not have any guarantee that $R(T) +_S \ker(S)=W$ since $R(T) +_S \ker(S)$ might as well be just a subspace of $W$, which maps to the whole $X$. I know it's obvious that $R(T) +_S \ker(S) \subset W$, but I can't prove that it's also the case that $W \subset R(T) +_S \ker(S)$ to finally prove that $W=R(T) +_S \ker(S)$.

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S: W \to X$ be a surjective linear map and $S \circ T: V \to X$ be a surjective linear map. Note that $T:V \to W$ is a linear map.

So, we will say that:

$$T(V) = \{w \in W: \exists v \in V: T(v) = w \}$$

$$ker(S) = \{w \in W: S(w) = 0 \}$$

Clearly, $T(V) + ker(S) \subset W$. Now, we just have to prove equality via mutual containment.

Let $w \in W$. Then, $S(w) \in X$. Since $S \circ T: V \to X$ is surjective, there exists a $v \in V$ so that:

$$S(T(v)) = S(w)$$

$$\implies S(T(v)) - S(w)= 0$$

$$\implies S(T(v) - w) = 0$$

$$\implies T(v) - w \in ker(S)$$

Now, we know that $T(v) \in T(V)$. So, $-T(v) \in T(V)$. Hence:

$$-T(v) + T(v) - w = -w \in T(V) + ker(S)$$

Now, we want to say that $w \in T(V) + ker(S)$ but we can't do that until we show that $T(V) + ker(S)$ is a subspace of $W$. Fortunately, proving this is easy. We just need to check 3 conditions:

1. $0 \in T(V) \land 0 \in ker(S) \implies 0+0 = 0 \in T(V) + ker(S)$
2. Let $w_1,w_2 \in T(V) + ker(S)$. So, each of them belong to either one of those two sets. In any case, $w_1 + w_2 \in T(V) + ker(S)$.
3. Let $\lambda \in F$ and $w \in T(V) + ker(S)$. So, there exists a $u \in T(V)$ and a $v \in ker(S)$ such that $w = u + v$. In other words, $\lambda \cdot u \in T(V)$ and $\lambda \cdot v \in ker(S)$. So, $\lambda \cdot u + \lambda \cdot v = \lambda \cdot w \in T(V) + ker(S)$.

Hence, $T(V) + ker(S)$ is a subspace of $W$. Hence, $w \in T(V)+ker(S)$. That proves that $T(V) + ker(S) = W$

Please have a look at the argument above and let me know if there are any mistakes in it :D

Comment: Thank you for your proof! I didn't really notice any mistakes. :)

Comment: You're welcome buddy :D